# Spring boot API returns ? for Cyrillic characters when deployed in AmazonLinux

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am creating a docker image where a spring boot application is deployed. The API works find locally but when deployed as a image from amazonlinux:2 the API returns ? for Cyrillic characters
eg. Request "Городское тестирование для адреса asos".
Response : "????????? ???????????? ??? ?????? asos A"

FROM amazonlinux:2
#FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN yum install -y java maven

ARG JAR_FILE=target/application-exec.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
RUN mkdir /data
RUN mkdir /src
EXPOSE 8002
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java -Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev /app.jar"]

Please let me know if anybody solved similar issue.

Comment: Fixed it using 
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=922034

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@RequestMapping(
 value = "/all", 
 method = RequestMethod.GET,
 produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
```

)

Удачи :)

Comment: I tried that as well, but that is not working either. Basically it works well when deployed on Local servers but not on amazonlinux:2